# Android Studio error related to Google Play Services

Tags: android-studio, webview, google-play-services

I get these errors while building a signed apk using Android Studio. Help me build the app please.

1.

> Error:(42, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').

2.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/home/dna/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="appen.woltlab_bb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="appen.woltlab_bb.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="appen.woltlab_bb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="appen.woltlab_bb.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
 ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try clean and build your project.

Comment: @isnotmenow , you mean start from scratch ?

Comment: No, clean you project from menu Build -> Clean.

Comment: @isnotmenow Thanks, I tried. But got the same errors again. :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. It was caused due to having accidentally including some auto generated API indexing code from a similar project by me. In case you have this issue, just start from scratch and be careful with what you import from your previous project.